# Why am I getting a read-only file system from github and an error when trying to install apache airflow?

Tags: github, airflow

I am working on VirtualBox 6.0 with Python 3.5. I am trying to install airflow from github using the requirements-python3.5.txt file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/v1-10-stable/requirements/requirements-python3.5.txt). However, when I try to download this file from the command line, I get a read-only file system:

```
    vagrant@learnairflow:~$ source .sandbox/bin/activate
    (.sandbox) vagrant@learnairflow:~$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/v1-10-stable/requirements/requirements-python3.5.txt
    --2020-06-13 15:47:54--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/v1-10-stable/requirements/requirements-python3.5.txt
    Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 199.232.48.133
    Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|199.232.48.133|:443... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 6210 (6.1K) [text/plain]
    requirements-python3.5.txt: Read-only file system

    Cannot write to ‘requirements-python3.5.txt’ (Success).
```

Subsequently, when I try to install airflow I get the following error:

```
(.sandbox) vagrant@learnairflow:~$ pip install "apache-airflow[celery, crypto, mysql, rabbitmq, redis]"==1.10.10 --constraint requirements-python3.5.txt
WARNING: The directory '/home/vagrant/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 288, in run
    wheel_cache = WheelCache(options.cache_dir, options.format_control)
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cache.py", line 296, in __init__
    self._ephem_cache = EphemWheelCache(format_control)
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cache.py", line 265, in __init__
    globally_managed=True,
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/temp_dir.py", line 137, in __init__
    path = self._create(kind)
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/temp_dir.py", line 185, in _create
    tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="pip-{}-".format(kind))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 358, in mkdtemp
    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 130, in _sanitize_params
    dir = gettempdir()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 296, in gettempdir
    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 231, in _get_default_tempdir
    dirlist)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/home/vagrant']
```

I've tried using the sudo command but it doesn't work either. Do you have any idea of what might be causing this error and how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the Vagrant box. (Implied from user name)